# Symfony Custom Repository class not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository-pattern, query-builder

I have a class

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="registration_number")
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PNC\MISDashboardBundle\Repositories\RegistrationNumberRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\Entity@EntityListeners({"RegistrationNumberListener"})
*/
class RegistrationNumber {
}
```

and the repo class

```
namespace PNC\MISDashboardBundle\Repositories;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

/**
 * RegistrationNumberRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class RegistrationNumberRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function findByTotalMatches($keyword)
    {
        /* your awesome code block */
        return 34;
    }
}
```

and I am calling the method in this way;

```
$check = $em->getRepository('PNCMISDashboardBundle:RegistrationNumber')
                                            ->findTotalMatches(5);
```

But it says that;

> Undefined method 'findTotalMatches'. The method name must start with
>   either findBy or findOneBy!

I have built lot of other custom repo and works, i don't know that wrongs with this one. has anyone any hint what is wrong with this.

Comment: Maybe having `@ORM\Entity` twice (three times actually) is the problem. I think you should clean up the annotations for `RegistrationNumber` and try again.

Answer (score 3):

As said in comment,

Change :

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="registration_number")
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PNC\MISDashboardBundle\Repositories\RegistrationNumberRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\Entity@EntityListeners({"RegistrationNumberListener"})
*/
class RegistrationNumber {
```

To :

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="registration_number")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PNC\MISDashboardBundle\Repositories\RegistrationNumberRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
* @ORM\EntityListeners({"RegistrationNumberListener"})
*/
class RegistrationNumber {
```

And it should works.

Comment: yes, the repo was working, but but just checked the listener is not working.

Comment: I'm talking about the listener. If it was not working before you ask the question, there is no relation between your actual question and this problem. Look more at the [doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners), you'll make it working. Good luck